# Messy self-join Mysql SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return a list of product id's that are...

1. Within a specific category (for example 'Clothing')
2. Which have various attributes, such as 'Red' or 'Green'
3. Which are themselves within attribute 'groups' such as 'Color'

I'm getting stuck when I need to select MULTIPLE attribute options within MULTIPLE attribute groups. For example, if I need to return a list of products where Color is 'blue' OR 'red' AND size is 'Medium' OR 'XXL'.

This is my code:

```
SELECT `products.id` 
FROM 
`products` , 
`categories` ,
`attributes` att1, 
`attributes` att2   
WHERE products.id = categories.productid 
AND `categories.id` = 3 
AND att1.productid = products.id
AND att1.productid = att2.productid
AND 
(att1.attributeid = 58 OR att1.attributeid = 60)
AND 
(att2.attributeid = 12 OR att2.attributeid = 9)
```

I believe this code works, but It looks pretty messy and I'm not sure my 'dirty' self-join is the correct way to go. Has anyone got any ideas on a more 'elegant' solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the modern join syntax:

```
SELECT products.id
FROM products 
join categories on products.id = categories.productid
join attributes att1 on att1.productid = products.id 
join attributes att2 on att1.productid = att2.productid
WHERE categories.id = 3 
AND att1.attributeid IN (58, 60)
AND att2.attributeid IN (12, 9)
```

It's easier to read because it clearly demarques *join* conditions from *row filtering* conditions. It's also easier for the SQL optimizer to identify these distinctions and create better query plans

#### Edited

I alsp added the use of `IN (...)`. Not only does it look nicer, the DB wil use an index with `IN` but usually *not* with `OR`, even though they mean the same thing

Comment: I think you should use `IN (...)` instead of `... OR ...` and add `SELECT DISTINCT` or rather `GROUP BY (products.id)` (somehow I get a feeling he need each product just once).

Comment: Excellent, will make sure I use the syntax you mentioned, it DOES look far neater. Thanks very much for your advice everyone!

Comment: @Vyktor Can't believe I missed the `IN`. Updated answer. Good one.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM   products p
JOIN   categories  c ON  c.productid = p.id
JOIN   attributes a1 ON a1.productid = p.id
JOIN   attributes a2 ON a2.productid = p.id
WHERE  categories.id = 3 
AND    a1.attributeid IN (58, 60)
AND    a2.attributeid IN (12,  9)
```

I think you had a mistake where you join the second attribute to the first attribute instead of joining it to the product. I fixed that.

On second thought, this may be intentional, and my correction wrong. It is a messy design, though, to mix attributes with attribute groups in the same table.

I also simplified your syntax and use explicit JOINs which are more readable.